# Bitbucket - SourceTree is acting up

Tags: git, authentication, version-control, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I am having a problem with authentication of my Bitbucket account in SourceTree. All was fine as of yesterday.

On my current branch, when I *pull*, I get the following:

[image]

The BitBucket login prompt appears, and each time I try logging in it fails repeatedly, and the prompt appears again:

[image]

Hence the several "Logon failed" messages.

I have tried resetting my password. I am able to access both Bitbucket & Jira (from Atlassian) in the browser.

My account settings also appear to be proper in Tools -> Preferences -> Authentication:

[image]

The account I am using has a valid logon token:

[image]

What is this authentication problem? And how can I resolve it? It doesn't seem to be a problem with my account, as I can access Bitbucket / Jira in Chrome. Someone please help.

I have referred to the following posts:

**1.** [Getting "fatal: Authentication failed for..." error](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Sourcetree-questions/Getting-quot-fatal-Authentication-failed-for-quot-error/qaq-p/624663).

**2.** [How to update your Git credentials on Windows](https://cmatskas.com/how-to-update-your-git-credentials-on-windows/).

Answer (score 0):

Try doing the same through command line/Tortoise git. If you encounter the same issue at both the places, there's definitely some problem with your credentials.

If you are able to *pull* using any of the above methods, try  to *pull* through SourceTree again  and see if the issue still persists.